# Is there any scenario when we would resort to a process instead of a goroutine?

Tags: go

I understand that goroutines are very light weight and we can spawn thousands of them but I want to know if there is some scenario when we should spawn a process instead of a goroutine (like hitting some kind of process boundaries in terms of resource or something else). Can spawning a new process in some scenario be beneficial in terms of resource utilization or some other dimension?

Comment: Given that you can light up a system like a Christmas tree just using Goroutines (depending on `GOMAXPROCS`), I fail to see how the added complexity of cross-process communication would be any better. But as the close votes note, this is primarily opinion based, which makes it off topic.

Answer (score 2):

To get things started, here's three reasons. I'm sure there's more.

**Reason #1**

In a perfect world, CPUs would be busy doing the most important work they can (and not wasted doing the less important work while more important work waits).

To do this, whatever controls what work a CPU does (the scheduler) has to know how important each piece of work is. This is normally done with (e.g.) thread priorities. When there are 2 or more processes that are isolated from each other, whatever controls what work a CPU does can't be part of either process. Otherwise you get a situation where one process is consuming CPU time doing unimportant work because it can't know that there's a different process that wants the CPU for more important work.

This is why things like "goroutines" are broken (inferior to plain old threads). They simply can't do the right thing (unless there's never more than one process that wants CPU time).

Processes (combined with "process priorities") can fix that problem (while adding multiple other problems).

**Reason #2**

In a perfect world, software would never crash. The reality is that sometimes processes do crash (and sometimes the reason has nothing to do with software - e.g. a hardware flaw). Specifically, when one process crashes often there's no sane way to tell how much damage was done within that process, so the entire process typically gets terminated. To deal with this problem people use some form of redundancy (multiple redundant processes).

**Reason #3**

In a perfect world, all CPUs and all memory would be equal. In reality things don't scale up like that, so you get things like ccNUMA where a CPU can access memory in the same NUMA domain quickly, but the same CPU can't access memory in a different NUMA domain as quickly. To cope with that, ideally (when allocating memory) you'd want to tell the OS "this memory needs low latency more than bandwidth" (and OS would allocate memory for the fastest/closest NUMA domain only) or you'd tell the OS "this memory needs high bandwidth more than low latency" (and the OS would allocate memory from all NUMA domains). Sadly every language I've ever seen has "retro joke memory management" (without any kind of "bandwidth vs. latency vs. security" hints); which means that the only control you get is the choice between "one process spread across all NUMA domains vs. one process for each NUMA domain".

Comment: Probably the most important/common reason to use separate processes would be for privilege separation.